# Thymeleaf bind a String field to a select box

Tags: string, select, thymeleaf

```
@GetMapping("add")
public String addPart(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("suppliers",  this.partService.getSupplierNames());
    model.addAttribute("part", new AddPartViewModel());
    return "parts/parts-add";
}
```

This is my class

```
    public class AddPartViewModel
    {
        private String name;
        private double price;
        private int quantity;
        private String supplierName;
  //PUBLIC GETERS AND SETTERS AND AN EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR
}
```

Thymeleaf syntax

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="supplierName">Example select</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="supplierName">
                        <option th:each="name : ${suppliers}" th:text="${name}" th:field="*{supplierName}"></option>
                    </select>
       </div>
```

This is the only place where i get error on. The rest of the fragment works correctly, even if just remove the `th:field` tag the `List<String> suppliers` parces it self correctly in to the select box. Not i tried to put the th:field in the `<select>` tag as well, i.e

```
            <select class="form-control" id="supplierName" th:field="*{supplierName}">
```

but still i get an error during parcing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:field` reffers to a form-backing bean's field, so make sure you've provided the proper bean in a `<form>` tag (using `th:object` attribute).

Regarding select: `th:field` should be provided in a `<select>` tag, like you've attempted to do. But you should provide also the proper `th:value` attribute in a `<option>` tag, so that any value could be assigned to the field.

Your form containing the problematic select should look like this:

```
<form th:object="${part}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplierName">Example select</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{supplierName}">
            <option th:each="name : ${suppliers}" th:value="${name}" th:text="${name}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- the rest of form's inputs and buttons -->

</form>
```

Comment: ye th value did the job for me